# lit-element: can't get an array of objects to render output in loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, render, lit-element

Just starting with lit-element

in my render i have:

```
  return html`
   ${this.jobCreate}
   ${this.jobDetails}
  `;
```

get jobCreate works fine

this is my get jobDetails:

```
  get jobDetails() {
    const jobs = [
      { name: "phoenix job", location: "phoenix", expires: "2020-10-01" },
      { name: "chicago job", location: "chicago", expires: "2020-10-01" },
      { name: "pittsburgh job", location: "pittsburgh", expires: "2020-10-01" },
    ];

    return html`<ul>
      ${jobs.forEach((job) => html`<li>${job.name}</li>`)}
    </ul>`;
  }
```

inspecting the element i can see an empty `<ul>` set

if do a `<ul><li>${jobs[2].name}</li></ul>` that works

if i console out job, i can see all the right job print 3 times in the loop

I can't understand why i can't get the `<li>` to render in the loop

i used this for reference: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#template-syntax-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `forEach` instead of `map` for looping the `jobs` array. `forEach` returns undefined whereas `map` returns a new array with every value mapped according to the function given.

As an alternative way of thinking about it, if you took out the template literal tags and output a string `'undefined'` when a value is `undefined`, `forEach` will output the following:

```html
<ul>
     undefined
</ul>
```

whereas `map` would output:

```html
<ul>
    <li>phoenix job</li><li>chicago job</ul><ul>pittsburgh job</ul>
</ul>
```

The following is likely what you're aiming for:

```js
get jobDetails() {
    const jobs = [
        { name: "phoenix job", location: "phoenix", expires: "2020-10-01" },
        { name: "chicago job", location: "chicago", expires: "2020-10-01" },
        {
            name: "pittsburgh job",
            location: "pittsburgh",
            expires: "2020-10-01",
        },
    ];

    return html`<ul>
        ${jobs.map((job) => html`<li>${job.name}</li>`)}
    </ul>`;
}
```

#### Further reading:

- [MDN on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [MDN on forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: i looked at both of those docs for each of those before, and again now, and I still can't see why foreach wouldn't work as well, because there weren't any undefined, but i see why map would be better for the reasons you gave

map did work, i guess I have more "lernin" to do.  thanks 